# What is a Dime Word™?

Tags: word, pattern, word-property

*This puzzle is based off the [What is a Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=what%20is%20a%20word%E2%84%A2) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463/jlee)*

If a word satisfies a certain property it is called a **Dime Word™**. Here are some examples:

| Dime Words™ | Not Dime Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| KARMA | ECHO |
| PHOENIX | THUNDERBIRD |
| PANTHEON | VALKYRIE |
| CYPHER | ZERO |
| VIPER | LESION |
| RAZE | REAPER |
| BREACH | BASTION |
| SAGE | MAESTRO |
| TALON | SIGMA |
| KINDRED | MERCY |
| RUMBLE | PULSE |
| NAUTILUS | LION |

CSV:

```
Dime Words™,Not Dime Words™
KARMA,ECHO
PHOENIX,THUNDERBIRD
PANTHEON,VALKYRIE
CYPHER,ZERO
VIPER,LESION
RAZE,REAPER
BREACH,BASTION
SAGE,MAESTRO
TALON,SIGMA
KINDRED,MERCY
RUMBLE,PULSE
NAUTILUS,LION
```

What is the rule to tell whether a word is a Dime Word™ or not? Why is it called a Dime Word™?

(Note that each word can be tested for whether it is a Dime Word™ on its own, without looking at any of the other words in the list of examples. And hello from the Maths Stack.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A Dime Word is

> a playable character from a Riot Games video game.
>  PHOENIX, CYPHER, VIPER, RAZE, BREACH, SAGE are all [agents in Valorant](https://playvalorant.com/en-us/agents/), and
>  KARMA, PANTHEON, TALON, KINDRED, RUMBLE, NAUTILUS are all [champions in League of Legends](https://na.leagueoflegends.com/en-us/champions/).

And it's called a Dime Word because

> Riot Games is a subsidiary of Tencent.

Incidentally,

> there's also a relationship between the Not Dime words:
>  ECHO, THUNDERBIRD, VALKYRIE, ZERO, LESION, MAESTRO, PULSE, LION are [operators in Rainbow Six Siege](https://rainbowsix.fandom.com/wiki/Operators), and
>  ECHO (again!), REAPER, BASTION, SIGMA, MERCY are [heroes in Overwatch](https://overwatch.fandom.com/wiki/Heroes).

Comment: puzzle was too easy because all the words could directly be googled